# How do I place a function in a standalone page?

Tags: functions, rss

Im trying to a a function to create an rss feed from a gmail dress. This works if i place it in functions.php, but overtakes my site as an rssfeed, as expected. How do I place it in a standalone page, something like /gmailrss?

The snippet if needed:

```
 function checkGmail($username, $password)
  { 
 $url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom"; 

 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
 $mailData = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);

 return $mailData;
 }

 header('Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
 $feed = checkGmail("gmail", "password");
 echo $feed;
```

Comment: Create a custom [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and then create a page with your desired slug and assign it to that template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just going to output your own data, there's no reason to wait for the main query to run. Hook `parse_request` and check if your page was requested and run your code there.

```
function wpd_maybe_output_feed( $request ){
    if( isset( $request->query_vars['pagename'] )
        && 'gmailrss' == $request->query_vars['pagename'] ){
            header('Content-Type:text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
            echo checkGmail("gmail", "password");
            die;
    }
    return $request;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_maybe_output_feed' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo and AndrewBartel.. couldn't get the second snippet to work, however the first works now. it outputs the feed on my custom page, but i can't get a working validated rss feed from it, it defaults to my site.com/feed. Any pointers there? used this guide: http://www.internoetics.com/2012/08/08/create-a-gmail-rss-feed/